# WCF - How can I know what is the host name of the computer that connects to me

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I know what is the host name of the computer that connects to me.

**Example:**

Computer A and Computer B become Hosts and Computer A want to connect computer B.

Computer A
IP : 1.2.3.4
Host name : StavComputer
**AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(InterfaceForService), BasicHttpBinding1, "StavComputer");

Im computer B and Computer A connecting to me and I want to know what is his Host name that in this case is StavComputer.

Is this possibol?! What I get if Computer A dont have Host Name becouse he doesnt host at all?! I hope you understood !

Comment: All machines will have an identifier; even if it is a Workstation Id or an IP Address.  They will always have some identifier. But on the code that exists on Clients consuming just use: `Environment.MachineName` then handle that on your Server.

Answer (score 3):

Extract remote endpoint name/IP from OperationContext, and try to resolve host name by IP.

```
var prop = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
var remp = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(remp.Address);
string hostName = hostEntry.HostName;
```

Comment: this is not what i ment but tnx for trying. anyway, is there a way to know what is the address of the computer that connecting to me?

Comment: RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Address contains IP address of computer that is connecting to you.